# Adding a variable in a Liquid template for multilingual?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll project and I'm trying to implement multilingual functionality.

My data files were stored in `_data/my_data.yml`, and accessed in the templates via the `{% for data in site.data.my_data %}` Liquid template tag.

I have now copied and translated my data files into `_data/en/my_data.yml` and `_data/it/my_data.yml` and created two `.md` files, using the same template, with respective `lang` attributes in the front matter.

I am trying to dynamically access the correct data based on this `lang` attribute however it's throwing all sorts of errors.

**Things I've tried**

```
{% for data in site.data.[page.lang].my_data %}
{% for data in site.data[page.lang]my_data %}
{% for data in site.data.{{page.lang}}.my_data %}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone runs into this in the future, solved it with pretty much the only combination I hadn't tried yet:

```
{% for data in site.data[page.lang].my_data %}
```